# Find files in different folders on remote with `find` and copy to local

Tags: bash, ssh, find, rsync

So I found several geotiffs in different locations on a server which I SSHed into. Now I'm a little lost of how to copy all at once to my local machine. I would like to avoid doing a

`scp user@remote:/path/to/file .`  for every geotiff.

So I'm on my server here and found with `find . -type f -iname *.tif` those files:

```
./20200911_20200923/intensity/20200911_20200923.disp.real.geo.tif
./20200911_20200923/intensity/20200911_20200923.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20200911_20200923/intensity/20200911_20200923.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20200103_20200115/intensity/20200103_20200115.disp.real.geo.tif
./20200103_20200115/intensity/20200103_20200115.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20200103_20200115/intensity/20200103_20200115.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20190917_20190929/intensity/20190917_20190929.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20190917_20190929/intensity/20190917_20190929.disp.real.geo.tif
./20190917_20190929/intensity/20190917_20190929.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20170915_20170927/intensity/20170915_20170927.disp.real.geo.tif
./20170915_20170927/intensity/20170915_20170927.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20170915_20170927/intensity/20170915_20170927.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20190108_20190120/intensity/20190108_20190120.disp.real.geo.tif
./20190108_20190120/intensity/20190108_20190120.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20190108_20190120/intensity/20190108_20190120.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20170106_20170118/intensity/20170106_20170118.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20170106_20170118/intensity/20170106_20170118.disp.real.geo.tif
./20170106_20170118/intensity/20170106_20170118.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20160827_20160908/intensity/20160827_20160908.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20160827_20160908/intensity/20160827_20160908.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20160827_20160908/intensity/20160827_20160908.disp.real.geo.tif
./20180113_20180125/intensity/20180113_20180125.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20180113_20180125/intensity/20180113_20180125.disp.real.geo.tif
./20180113_20180125/intensity/20180113_20180125.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20180910_20180922/intensity/20180910_20180922.disp.mag.geo.tif
./20180910_20180922/intensity/20180910_20180922.disp.imag.geo.tif
./20180910_20180922/intensity/20180910_20180922.disp.real.geo.tif
```

Now the question is how to copy all of them to my local machine. I know of scp and rsync but I'm not really familiar besides the complete basics. I would appreciate any help:)bash

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `scp user@remote:20*/intensity/*.tif .`

Comment: At least if the files paths in the question are all the files you want to download that format should fit. If the format of the file paths gets more complicated you'd need some more advanced things.

Comment: This solution is based on the fact that you can use wildcards multiple times on different levels of file paths.